# Running a conda environment unable to use keyboard library in my script. Getting Errors

Tags: python, ubuntu, keyboard, importerror, anaconda3

I'm trying to run a python script after activating my conda environment and installing the necessary packages.

```
import keyboard

current_key = ''
buffer = []

if not os.path.exists('captures'):
os.makedirs('captures')

def keyboardCallBack(key: keyboard.KeyboardEvent):
'''
This function is called when a keyboard event occurs. It stores the key pressed in a buffer and sorts it.

    ### Arguments : 
    `key (KeyboardEvent)`
    
    ### Returns : 
    `None`
    
    ### Example : 
    `keyboardCallBack(key)`
    '''
    
    global current_key
    
    if key.event_type == 'down' and key.name not in buffer:
        buffer.append(key.name)
    
    if key.event_type == 'up':
        buffer.remove(key.name)
    
    buffer.sort() # Arrange the keys pressed in ascending order
    current_key = " ".join(buffer) # Convert the list to a string

keyboard.hook(callback=keyboardCallBack)
i = 0
```

When I run `python captures.py` I initially got an error "ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux".

I ran `sudo /home/jrbauti1/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python captures.py`, but now it's giving me this error.

> /home/jrbauti1/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py:110: UserWarning: Failed to create a device file using `uinput` module. Sending of events may be limited or unavailable depending on plugged-in devices.
> device = aggregate_devices('kbd')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/jrbauti1/projects/machine_learning_dino_game/captures.py", line 40, in <module>
> keyboard.hook(callback=keyboardCallBack)